# How to retrieve shapes (Triangle , Square , Lines , textbox) from word document to python using docx or docx2python library?

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I am working with word documents with the python docx library. I am able to extract all the paragraphs, tables, images from the word document. But Along with this, I want to detect non-image shapes but I am not able to figure out how to extract them. Can somebody help me out?

I am already going through multiple StackOverflow questions but have not been able to find a good way to do this.

Comment: `python-docx` has no support for non-image shapes (and only limited support for "inline" image shapes).